# Rebuild Index Task options

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, maintenance-plans, index-maintenance

I have to debug a performance issue on a SQL Server 2016 database. The query was pretty simple - a few temporary tables joined with SQL tables and aggregation. The amount of rows of involved in temporary tables was really small (several tables, hundreds of rows).

I have found that one of the tables PK has 12% index fragmentation. If the table was removed from the query it runs faster. I rebuilt the index and everything was fine.

I believe there must be something wrong with the settings of the SQL Server 2016 instance, because the query is running perfectly fine on SQL Server 2014. The only difference I have found in the settings was in the maintenance plans - the pictures below shows the plans:

#### SQL Server 2016

[image]

#### SQL Server 2014

[image]

I guess there is something not set correctly in the *Index Stats Options*, which is causing statistics not to be recalculated. Can anyone tell me if am I am right (as I am not DBA) or say if the plan looks OK, so I can search for the issue in another place?

Comment: I have to note that the SQL 2016 maintenance task doesn't seem to be configured, so it's hard to know if any index maintenance is actually happening there. Agree with [@Kin 's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/157109/116653) re, using Ola Hallengren scripts, and importance of stats updates.

Answer (score 0):

*This is longer than a comment .. so putting this as answer ...*

> So, I have rebuild the index and everything was fine.

Rebuilding an index will [update stats on the columns associated with that index](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2015/03/06/does-rebuild-index-update-statistics/).

There can be a lot of variables which might be different between 2 servers (2014 vs 2016)

- sys.configurations settings
- compatiblity level of database
- Any custom trace flag enabled
- max memory setting
- cost threshold of parallelism setting
- max dop setting

You can run [Best practice analyzer script](https://github.com/Microsoft/tigertoolbox/tree/master/BPCheck) from MSSQLTiger team or just run [sp_Blitz](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/) from Brent Ozar's team.

As a side note: Use [Ola's Index maintenance solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) ... much flexible and well tested by a lot of organizations.

From your screenshot, it seems that you are setting the page fullness (FILLFACTOR) to 80% i.e. leave 20% free. You should monitor fragmentation (in your case 12% is nothing + you need to consider how many pages are in the index. I would suggest you to start looking into indexes with 1000+ pages). I would doubt that this will cause a major performance problem.

Comment: Yes, I know rebuilding the PK rebuilds the NI and updates statistics. That's why I think there is something wrong with the DB maintenance plan. Everything you mention is the same, except the `trace flags` -  they must be set with their default values on both instance, but I will check them, too.

Comment: What trace flags are different?

Comment: `DBCC TRACESTATUS` returns nothing on both instances, so I guess everything is the same as set up, instead these options in the maintenance plan.

Comment: I mean `except` the diff in the maintenance plans.